# How to open a corporate account on Bitstamp?

Tags: bitcoin-core-accounts, bitstamp, aml, know-your-customer

I am trying to open a corporate account on Bitstamp, but there are so many questions to answer, is there any easy way to get approved?

How are you supposed to answer: Is your business regulated for AML? If so, what is your specific policy? Specifically, how do you perform KYC for your customers?

Answer (score 2):

If your (UK) business is in an area where you have specific regulations to follow for anti-money laundering, and you do, you will already know the answer. (If it is not in the UK, you may have to find out if dealing with UK-registered Bitstamp means you'll have to start complying with UK law and its requirements like KYC: Know Your Customer.) Otherwise,  the first answer is likely no and the follow-up questions are not applicable.

Commonly, KYC includes requiring a scan or photocopy of customer's photoid (passport or driving permit) and
of a proof of address (utility bill), and checking that they are not on a list of people the UK does not allow you to do business with.